# Get image src using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the `src` attribute of an html image. It seems like I can find the `img` element in the DOM but the `src` attribute is undefined, any ideas why?

**HTML:**

```
<table id="comboTable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;" data-bind="click: $root.selectCombo">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img class="selector" src="~/Images/roundOffButton.png" style="position: absolute;margin-left: -57px; margin-top: -35px;" />
        </td>
        <td style="height: 35px;">
            <table style="width: 100%; background-color: #0097D8;padding:5px;">
                <tr style="padding:5px;">
                    <td style="height: 36px; padding-left: 14px; font-weight: bold;color: black; margin: 1px; width: 70%; text-align:left;">
                        <span data-bind="text: Description" style="padding-left: 5px;" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 30%;padding:8px; text-align: center;color: white; background-color:black;">
                        <span data-bind="text: formatCurrency(Price)" style="font-size: 14px; white-space: nowrap;
                            font-weight: bold;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var comboSpan = $("span:contains('" + description + "')");

var img = $(comboSpan).closest(".selector");

alert('Image object - ' + img);

var src = $(img).attr('src'); 

alert(src); //src is undefined
```

Comment: `var img = $(comboSpan).closest(".selector");` is a wrong selector. Both the elemnts are in a different parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xj89f/)**

- Use a valid selector for `img`, `img` and `span` have different parent, so you can't use `closest()` directly in this case.
- Also `comboSpan,img` is already a jQuery objects. You don't need it like `$(comboSpan)`
- Use `.closest('#comboTable')` as your hierarcy has a table inside a table.

  ```
  <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <img>                      //You need this.
           </td>

           <td>
               <table>
                     <tr>
                           <td>
                                <span>    //You have this.
                           </td>

                     </tr>
               </table>
           </td>
       </tr>
  </table>
  ```

---

**Final code:**

```
var comboSpan = $("span:contains('" + description + "')");

var img = comboSpan.closest('#comboTable').find('.selector');    //Change this line

alert('Image object - ' + img);
var src = img.attr('src'); 
alert(src); //src is undefined
```

Comment: you are missing quotes for .selector

Comment: Thank you, I see my mistake now. This is the only right answer because the closest tr doesn't have an image with a .selector class but the comboTable does

Answer (score 0):

You need to find closest `tr` and then `.selector` img :

```
var comboSpan = $("span:contains('" + description + "')");

var img = $(comboSpan).closest("tr").find(".selector");// find tr and then img

alert('Image object - ' + img);

var src = $(img).attr('src'); 

alert(src); //src is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You first try to find `tr` and then it's child `img` (i.e `.selector`)

```
var img = $(comboSpan).closest('tr').find('.selector');
```

Try this:

```
var comboSpan = $("span:contains('" + description + "')");
var img = $(comboSpan).closest('tr').find('.selector');
alert('Image object - ' + img);
var src = $(img).attr('src'); 
alert(src);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var img = comboSpan.closest('tr').find('.selector');
// no need to wrap comboSpan with jquery as comboSpan is already a jquery object
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out with this.

```
$('.img1 img').attr('src');
```

Comment: Please, add some more information, why you're proposing this solution etc. Answers as short as this one shouldn't be formulated as answers, rather as a question's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you use as below:

```
var src = $('.selector').attr('src'); 

alert(src);
```

Answer (score -1):

My answer is belove

```
$('.img1 img').attr('src');
```